# What does “boot” mean here?

Tags: meaning

I’m reading Kipling’s *Kim*, ch 2, pg 37 says

> `Beggars aplenty have I met, and holy men to **boot**, but never such a *yogi* nor such a disciple,’ said the woman.

What does *boot* mean here, is it a verb or a noun and what’s the meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per Collin's Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-boot), **to boot** is a phrase and is used for emphasis

> You can say **to boot** to emphasize that you have added something else to something or to a list of things that you have just said.
>
> [formal, emphasis] 
>   *He is making money and receiving free advertising
>   to boot!*
>  
>   *They have to be thin, attractive and well-dressed to boot.*

Though the phrase has other meanings too, I think here, **to boot** is being used for emphasis only**

Answer (score 7):

to boot   [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/to%20boot)

> The adverb to boot is another way to say "as well" or "in addition."; in addition, by way of addition; furthermore.

As in:

> You could say that your cat is not only adorable, but clever to boot.

and in:

> `Beggars aplenty have I met, and holy men as well, ...

Answer (score 1):

The usage of the phrase 'to boot' is explained by the 
 [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/21513?rskey=6mxJC9&result=1#eid)'s *primary meaning* for the word 'boot' :

> a. Good: in phrase to boot: ‘to the good’, to advantage, into the bargain, in addition; besides, moreover.
>
> Etymology: Common Germanic: Old English bót (feminine), corresponds to Old Frisian bôte ...
>
> 1660   S. Pepys Diary 13 Feb. (1970) I. 54   For two books that I had and 6s. 6d to boot, I had my great book of songs

It seems to me that there is a connection with the word 'booty' :

> 1. orig. Plunder, gain, or profit acquired in common and destined to be divided among the winners.
>
> Etymology: The modern as well as the early forms, point to a Middle English long ō

[OED 2](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/21557?rskey=8zPQ2u&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)